# Display the list of users who have access to my project in SVN

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I am new to sub versions realm and picking up stuff as and when needed. My exposure with subversion is up to check-in , check out, create a new branch pretty petty stuff.
I am currently using: TortoiseSVN 1.7.5, Build 22551 and would like to know if there is a way to pull the list of users/usernames who have access to my specific project. is it possible to do from my remote machine where I run the  TortoiseSVN or would i have to be on the actual repository server where the subversion is being hosted on.

Please advice.

Thanks,

Alex

Answer (score 2):

Subversion doesn't publish the access rights in effect on a repository, but you can obtain a list of authors who have written to the repository. It's a very crude approximation, but it's something.

On a working copy, *TortoiseSVN->Show log* displays the commits as a table; the author is in column 3:

[image: TortoiseSVN->Show log screenshot]You can sort by clicking on a column header.

To do this on a repository for which you haven't checked out a working copy, use *TortoiseSVN->Repo-browser*, provide the repository URL, authenticate if necessary, rightclick->*Show log*.

This won't give you the list of authors without duplications.

I use the command line for that.  For instance, on Linux or Cygwin, you can use

```
svn log -q -r1:HEAD $url | awk -F ' | ' '/^r/ && !seen[$3]++ {print $3}'
```

where `$url` is the URL of your repository.

Answer (score 1):

It helps to first understand how Subversion access control is managed. The manual [has an entire chapter dedicated to this](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.serverconfig.html)

Once you know how your repository is hosted & configured, you can only know who has access to what by looking at the authorization configuration file that's stored on the server itself (unless the server is running 1.8 and the authz file is stored in the repository).

If you don't have access to the server and its configuration to either look at that file or find out where it is, there's nothing you can do.